# How to read a text file in Java and split it?

Tags: java

I need help with writting a program, which will read me a file in Java and then split the words and will count the average of notes. So I have a file in Java called dziennik.txt and there in two lines I have a name, surname, the number of notes and then the notes of a student. It looks like this:

Mark Stank 3 4 5 6

Veronica Lee 2 2 4

So what I need to do is split words so that program will know that the 3 word is a number of notes and the next ones are these notes and it will count the average. For now I have sth like this:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileWrite {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        StringBuilder dziennik = new StringBuilder();

        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("dziennik.txt"))) {

            // read line by line
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                dziennik.append(line).append("\n");
                String[] pair = line.split(" ");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }

        System.out.println(dziennik);
    }

}
```

I am new to this, so please explain this to me as simple as it can be .

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The code you posted looks like a great start to your homework assignment. If it helps, you can access any element in an array by its zero-based index (e.g. `pair[2]` is the 3rd element).

Comment: To be honest I am not quite sure what to do next. I don't know how to count the average of the notes, I mean how can i tell my program to take third word (in this case a number) of every line and use it later to calculate the average?

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a variable to store the total number of notes and a variable to store the sum of all notes (so you can determine average). Since the 3rd element of every line is the count of notes in that line, you can just loop from 2 to (count of notes - 1), parsing each note from string to int and adding them to your `sum` variable.

Comment: And how can I create a variable to store the sum of all notes and loop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what spork mentioned. Here's a way to get the average number of notes per student:

```
StringBuilder dziennik = new StringBuilder();
double total = 0; // Added line
double counter = 0; // Added line
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("dziennik.txt"))) {
    // read line by line
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        dziennik.append(line).append("\n");
        String[] pair = line.split(" ");
        total = total + Double.valueOf(pair[2]); // Added line
        counter++; // Added line
    }
    System.out.println("Average number of notes per student: " + total / counter); // Added line
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
}
System.out.println(dziennik);
```